What type of climate or geography would allow for a large mountain (10000m+) that glows when the sunlight hits the rockface?
The idea behind this is that there is a large mountain in my world that can be seen from the capital city over 500 km away. I took inspiration from Denali in Alaska, and how it can be seen from Anchorage on a clear day. I've obviously turned the scales up a bit for this.
The "novelty" of this mountain is that the southern rock face (seen from the city) gets hit with harsh sunlight and "glows/sparkles" gold (hence its name, Gold peak). I had the idea that it could be in a rainy climate, so the wet rock would shine brighter, but this won't account for the massive amount of snow which would probably dull the glow.
Perhaps the region could be so dry that even in higher altitudes, the mountain stays near clear of snow. (I am fine with some snowfall). I thought maybe something with virga storms surrounding the top enough to give it the wet shine that can be seen from far away.
At the end of the day, this is science fantasy, and I'm no ecologist, but any ideas would be helpful!

At 500km away you need to factor in planet curvature. Large distance also means lots of opportunity for the view to be blocked by cloud, smog smoke etc(very anti glow). Having lived in a city with large mountains nearby in a rainy climate, wet/dry makes no particular difference. It would be more down to what material the mountain is made of and or how fresh the snow is.

Everest is 8839m high and I assume your 10,000m number refers to altitude at the peak, not the height of the mountain from valley floor to peak. If you climb Everest, the actual ascent is only 2,500m. A mountain with a 10,000m ascent on a rainy/snowy/windy world is a bit hard to believe. But, if it's the former, then it's believable. But my problem is the nature of reflected light over that distance. Brilliant reflections are seen as white, not gold. Anything seen as gold is, I believe, not visible at a 500km distance. How important is the color?

On an Earthlike world, you'll have a job getting a mountain that reaches up much higher than Everest does, because you run into problems like stuff sinking into the mantle underneath, and rock undergoing plastic flow because it is no longer structurally sound under the sheer mass above it, that sort of thing.
On a world with lower gravity (like Mars) that problem can be reduced, of course.

Perhaps the region could be so dry that even in higher altitudes, the mountain stays near clear of snow.

This is tricky and it doesn't bode well for the habitability of the surrounding landscape, which makes it rather difficult for a city to form there.
This is the Ojos del Salado, on the border between Argentina and Chile:

(image credit sergejf via wikipedia)
It is a volcano, which helps give the rocks a nice low albedo which probably doesn't help ice formation much. It is also in the extremely dry Atacama desert. It still gets a dusting of snow and some permanent (or at least, long-lived) ice patches at the top. If it were much shorter, it'd stay as ice free as you'd have liked, but to keep a 10000 m peak ice free might be impossible to combine with a world that's wet enough to sustain terrestrial-style life.
Could I suggest a slightly simpler possibility, though? A large face on the westward side of the mountain could do an excellent job of catching the rays of the setting sun (or obviously, an east face and the rising sun, depending on where your city is). Because of its sheer height, the peak will remain in the last rays of the sun after twilight has fallen over the land below it, which can look quite striking.
But combine this with the right sort of cloud conditions and you can get some impressive alpenglow:

(image credit BrettA343 via wikipedia)
Here, even after the sun is below the horizon, sunlight reflecting off suitably high clouds can still make the peak glow. This can extend the post-sunset time even further. Admittedly, it isn't very golden but the effect can be quite dramatic, especially with a suitably-shaped mountain, and no-one can deny it looks pretty fancy.

over 500 km away

This is problematic, as Gault Drakkor observed in a comment. The problem is that there's a lot of atmosphere to get in the way, and that atmosphere is often filled with dust and pollution and water vapor and all the rest. There are some wonderful examples of very long observations on Earth here on astropolis.pl including this one of Kangchenjunga at 520 km distance:

(image credit PawelKlak via wikipedia)
but the critical thing is that these images were taken from >10000 m altitude, where the air is much thinner and you're above most dust, clouds and so on. Unless your city is at the top of a probably uninhabitably high mountain, the residents will almost certainly not get such a good view.
Note also that the sheer height of the mountain (8586 m! one of the biggest!) is somewhat lost thanks to the sheer distance of the view. Distant mountains tend not to look so distinctly "mountainy" as closer ones, because they just can't be tall enough.

At the end of the day, this is science fantasy

Ultimately, you can handwave in whatever weird weather, altitude composition, geology and sunlight you want. The mountain could be artificial, for a start, maybe part of an old space elevator installation or something (which may or mayt not still exist, according to your needs). That sort of thing could have de-icing surfaces, and various bits of odd reflective equipment on the outside, after all.
But 500 km is a long way for a good view. I'd shrink that down a bit, if I were you.

I wonder if the rock face's reflectivity could be enhanced by adding a lot of some highly reflective (or refractive?) mineral. Perhaps a "super-quartz" or adamantine.

Active Volcano
You can have the mountain literally glow by giving it a caldera full of magma. If the lake of liquid rock has enough convection to keep cycling the surface layer without cooling, it’ll glow without sun, even at night or cloudy days. I know you asked “when sunlight hits the face”, but I wasn’t sure if that was “at least that much glow” or “exclusively that much glow”, so I went with this answer.
